# How to check song is purchased from iTune OR not?

Tags: ios, mpmediaitem

I'm getting all song list. But i want to filter song on behalf of purchased from iTune.

```
 MPMediaQuery *mq = [[MPMediaQuery alloc] init];

 [mq addFilterPredicate:[MPMediaPropertyPredicate                                                   predicateWithValue:@(MPMediaTypeAudioITunesU) forProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyMediaType]];

  NSArray *itemsFromGenericQuery = [mq items];

 NSLog(@"count %lu",(unsigned long)[itemsFromGenericQuery count]);
```

Can someBody help me to filter out `iTunes` Purchased song list ?

Comment: Did you find a way to do it? if so, please let me know. Thanks in advance

Comment: Get url for each Song's Asset. Check either url is NULL or not ?
All songs which returns null url are DRM protected.

Comment: Could you explain it in clear? I am new to it. are all songs that are downloaded from iTunes Store are DRM protected ?

Comment: http://support.apple.com/en-in/HT1711 
Go and check what is iTunes plus. Hope so you will get all your answer

Comment: Ok, are you saying that the songs we downloaded from internet contains DRM protection ? So, If we check like that, all No DRM protected files are from iTunes purchased?

How to link a button to iTunes Store (Not AppStore) from our app ?

Comment: will you clear what you want to do in your app ?

Comment: Yes.

I want to check 

1) Whether the song was downloaded from iTunes Or not.

2) This is another scenario, I have a song and if it was not purchased by the user, I want to show a button which navigates to iTunes Store to the desired song. 

3) If there is a way, want to check whether the song is purchased or not by the Apple Account.

Comment: its simple,  Song which are purchased from iTunes store will return AssetUrl as null and without purchased will not rerun null. Also you can check it by purchasing a song and try to return its url. Its rerun null. Only this is a simple way to distinguish song either purchased or no.

Comment: How to navigate an User to iTunes Store to a specific song from our app ?